# Android: DateFormat.getBestDateTimePattern API Level < 18 replacement

Tags: java, android, datetime, jodatime

[`getBestDateTimePattern()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/DateFormat.html#getBestDateTimePattern(java.util.Locale,%20java.lang.String))

Requires Android API Level 18, is there a suitable open source library (like I can use with Joda DateTime) which acts as an effective replacement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under the hood Android uses the [ICU4C library](http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4c/) via [JNI bindings](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/libcore/+/jb-mr2-release/luni/src/main/native/libcore_icu_ICU.cpp) and especially its [`icu::DateTimePatternGenerator::getBestPattern()`](http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4c/classicu_1_1DateTimePatternGenerator.html#a41a97e72ded1cd3f8257946cfe01c222) function.

Comment: Yea that is the right library, I think however the Android framework ports part of the library over so that it is compatible (out of the box I tried, didn't work to just drop in the java jar version).

Comment: @laalto How can we do this using Joda Time, is it possible?